# How to create spreadsheet from available XML data in c#?

Tags: c#

I have XML data in XML format into string variable. 
I want to save this XML data which is in string variable  into spreadsheet and send an email attachement of that generated spreadsheet.

Please suggest me approach for achieving this.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: There are many question on this topic already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184849/c-sharp-and-xml-spreadsheet-simple-question?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745269/how-to-generate-xls-xlsx-from-office-2003-xml-spreadsheet-programatically-in-c?rq=1 to reference just a few...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know how to flatten a potential tree structure into a spreadsheet. That depends on your XML format and spreadsheet layout and spreadsheet software. Without those information we won't be able to help you.

You can then use [the mail client class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) to send a [mail message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) with [attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx).